# How to write if condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript

PHP IF Condition:

```
-> <?php if($pet['pet_type'] == 'Lost'){echo $pet['pet_name'];}else{echo 'Please Help Me';}?>
```

JS IF:

```
<h3 class="title" style="word-break: break-all;">'+if(res[i].pet_type === 2){res[i].pet_name}else{+'Please help me'+}+'</h3>
```

Please help me where is a mistake. And How can I resolve this mistake?

Comment: Include complete code. See [mcve].

Comment: what do you want JS to do in place of php's `echo`? Write to the console? Write to a webpage?

Comment: Your if statement markup is fine. What's inside doesn't make sense.

Comment: what's with the '+'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `concatenate`  properly

```js
var concat = '';
concat = '<h3 class="title" style="word-break: break-all;">';

//if(res[i].pet_type === 2){
if(2 === 2) {

  //value = res[i].pet_name;
  value  = 'sssss';
}
else {
  value = 'Please help me'; 
}

concat+= value+'</h3>';
console.log(concat);
```